# How can I calculate the crop size (rect) of the UIImage with different resolution

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage, gpuimage

In my app, I have a 'Capture from Camera' function, I am using GPUImageFramework by Brad Larson (ty) , GPUImageStillCamera when capturing still images.

```
stillCamera = [[GPUImageStillCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto cameraPosition:
               AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
```

as you can see. the Session preset is `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` which in iPhone 4 gives me 1529x2048 output and with 4s (8mp) device gives me 2448x3264.

the image below is how I use the GPUStillCamera. here, there is  rectangle which is in this case, the crop rect of the captured image.

[image: Still camera output]

code snippet when I capture image.

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender
{
        [stillCamera capturePhotoAsJPEGProcessedUpToFilter:filter withCompletionHandler:^(NSData *processedJPEG, NSError *error){

        //1529x2048 when iPhone 4 and 2448x3265 when on 4s
        UIImage *rawImage = [[UIImage alloc]initWithCGImage:[[UIImage imageWithData:processedJPEG]CGImage]scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

       **CGRect rect = CGRect{?,?,?,?};**
       UIImage *imageFromRect = [rawImage imageAtRect:rect ];
}
```

My question here is. How can I  know the points (x,y,w,h) that I can pass to `imageAtRect` method that will draw subimage from the `rawImage`? and will get only the image portion within the rectangle (*regardless the resolution of the captured image*) as shown in the screen above? should I just do it manually or is there any math technique you can suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using GPUImage anyway, look at the GPUImageCropFilter. It will crop using image coordinate space with a value ranging from 0.0 to 1.0, ie: irrespective of image size

Comment: Paul makes a good point. The GPUImageCropFilter uses a normalized coordinate system, so it crops a rectangle that's independent of the resolution of the input picture and handles the resolution calculation for the output for you.

Comment: I have looked at it and yes it works as you guys just said here :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this image cropping class and libray file and you can get the size and with and origin position of the cropped `UIImage`.

http://code4app.net/ios/Custom-image-cropper/51e5f03f6803fac530000000

Plus if you want it can dynamically can change the size of the cropping image accordingly. Easy to use and implement. Please look into the tutorial once.